# How do I show a field value of a referenced field separately?

Tags: views, entities

I can not write english correctly and very well,I am sorry about this issue.please help me for solving my problem.

How do I show a field value of a referenced field separately with the Views or the Rules module?

I want to show only the referenced field value to visitors.for example :

I have a field (field_describtion) with label about you , So I want to reference to this field_describtion and when see the content field_describtion only show to visitors.
I add referenced field_describtion from a content type and after search on that field and select a field_describtion value when click on referenced field value linked to referenced node.BUT I want to after click on referenced field (referenced field_describtion) link to a page that show only field_describtion (with label about you) to visitors.

I any way to work with this idea ?

My drupal version is 7 and I used entityreference module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think found the solution.

I Create a views and add a relation to entityrefence field , So in field of the view I can add another field of referenced content.

for example if we added reference field to users,in a view can add relation to that reference field (go to relations part of views settings) and add another user fields like email or user picture in our views (from fields part of the views settings).picture and email of referenced user show to ours.

Sorry for bad english typing.I hope solve problem of somebody.